# Event After Successful Login PHP

Tags: php, events

Having a problem that has to do with the following script:

```
if ($getUserType == "Admin") {
    header("Location: overall_lascruses_users_list.php");
    exit();
} elseif ($getUserType == "LCLEmployee") {
    header("Location: overall_lascruses_users_list.php");
    exit();
} elseif ($getUserType == "Site_Admin") {
    header("Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id='.$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID'].'");
    exit();
} elseif ($getUserType == "Site_Manager" || $getUserType == "Site_User") {
    header("Location: Control_Panel_list.php");
    exit();
}
```

How this works is the following: after a user logs in, it picks up the user role and then redirects to a different screen accordingly to its role.

The script was working fine, until it was added the following part:

```
header("Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id='.$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID'].'");
```

What is wrong here?

Note: `$_SESSION["LasCrusesLocal_UserID"] = $data["lasCrusesUserID"];`

Comment: why put the session value in the url? why not just read the session? could be a major security issue

Comment: instead of `"Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id='.$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID'].'"`, use `"Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id=".$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID']` You have a quotes mixup!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: thank you to all, specially to @castis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
header("Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id='.$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID'].'");
```

should look like this:

```
header("Location: initial_admin_manage.php?id=".$_SESSION['LasCrusesUserID']);
```

Seee the single, double quotes in phph they don't act the same

You can put a var inside double quote and it will be treated as his var itself but not in single quotes (in most case anyway, depend on your config).

Comment: See the links castis posted in the comments above about quotes.